# Remove encapsulating <p> tags in phpMyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am building a blog on wordpress and have imported about 3000 posts from an old blog. All post_content fields have p tags encapsulating them and p tags for line breaks (instead of br), like for instance:

```
<p>Maecenas congue volutpat nisl<p>&nbsp;</p> sit amet imperdiet.</p>
```

How can I remove all encapsulating p tags but at the same time leave the line breaks untouched in phpMyadmin?

Comment: You want to remove them or interpret them as HTML marks?

Comment: Remove them from the database

Answer (score 0):

Since Wordpress runs on PHP, you can use this in PHP

```
$changes = array("<p>", "</p>");
$changed_text = str_replace($changes, "", "<p>Maecenas congue volutpat nisl<p>&nbsp;</p> sit amet imperdiet.</p>");
```

Then you put them back into the database after the stuff you want stripped is stripped.